# Python - socket grab only one message at a time

Tags: python, sockets

I am connecting to a server and sending a message. Below is the simplified code. The server will first respond with a specific acknowledge message and then the actual response

```
self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self._sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
self._sock.settimeout(0.1)

def ReqResp(self, msg, Addr=None):
    self._UDSSend(msg, targetAddr = Addr)
    return self._UDSRecv()

def _UDSRecv()
    resp = self._sock.recv(1024)
    # Extract payload from resp and check if it is an ACK (some parts excluded for brevity)
    if payload == 'ACK':
        resp = self._UDSRecv() # Got the ACK, now call again to get next response
```

What I find is that sometimes the server responds so quickly that both the ACK message and the actual command response message are collected by the first `recv()`. However, I would like to be handle to grab them one at a time - is there a way to do that? Do I need to configure my socket in a different way?

I understand that I could reduce the `recv()` buffer size but I cannot guarantee what the server will be sending (it might respond with the ACK or it may send something else that I need to handle differently).

Wireshark sees the ACK message and command response as separate frames so I am assuming this is possible but not sure how.

Comment: a bit strange to get an ack from server when you expect it to send you something. ack is needed when you send something to it, not the other way. the response itself is the ack

Comment: otherwise your client will have to send "ack for receiving ack" and your server will have to wait for that "ack for ack" in order to be able to send you the actual payload. that's redundant.

Comment: This is a special command & control sequence (not TCP ACK or anything). So, I send a command, the server ACK it (i.e. saying I got it and it is a valid request, I am processing). Finally, it gives the actual response.

Comment: If I send a command that is invalid (some invalid command or the message is not formed properly, etc) it will send a NACK only (this is, again, a proprietary NACK not TCP level or such).

Comment: i'm aware that we're not discussing tcp here. ever noticed the http response field called "status code"? it reflects all possible situations that may happen - valid request, invalid request, resource not found etc. and it is included into the SAME response with the payload (if any)

Comment: Apologies, I'm not understanding the point. Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

TCP sends a stream of bytes. It doesn't divide the bytes up into messages. It just sends the bytes and `recv` gets some of the bytes that are waiting. If you want to be able to divide the bytes up into messages, that's your job.

Comment: So how does Wireshark correctly show each one on a new line? i.e. as separate TCP segment (sorry if terminology is incorrect)?

Comment: @SimpleOne TCP is allowed to split up the bytes, or not split them up. The receiver can't rely on the splitting, it has to put them back together. Note that if you send 50000 bytes at once, it probably gets split up into several lines.

Comment: Just to clarify about this splitting up. In my case they are separate messages (not one long message that's split) What I am seeing is server sends 'message A' and then sends 'message B'. On some occasions, by the time I call ```recv()``` both A and B are in the buffer so ```recv()``` returns both of them. And, so, there is no way to read A first then B from the recv buffer (unless I split it myself)?

Comment: @SimpleOne Correct.